# undefined variable while passing data from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter

While passing data from controller to view i am getting a severe notice saying undefined variable
My controller file

```
$data['message']="Invalid username and password";
 $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
```

view file

```
   echo $message;
```

Comment: have you tried on view `<?php echo $message;?>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $data variable. Replace your code with this

```
$data = array();
$data['message']="Invalid username and password";
 $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$message` in view is string.
You can use.

```
echo $message
```

reference: [https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html][1]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php echo $message;?>
```

Further ensure that welcome_message view file has .php extention

Let me know if you require any further help